# C.C. Chang’s Explanation of Generated Submodels

Tags: model-theory

I have no issue with Chang and Keisler’s definition of “submodels generated by...” but I’m extremely confused with how they go on to define the universe of the certain submodel $B$ generated by $X$ (a nonempty subset of $A$, a model for the language $L$). 
They state the following:

$$B = \{t[x_1,\dots,x_n] : t\text{ is a term of $L$ and }x_1,\dots,x_n\in X\}$$

Why must this be so?

Comment: What is their definition of the submodel generated by $X$?  The smallest submodel that contains $X$?

Comment: Is there an example you have in mind where you think it should be otherwise? (Note that $t$ is allowed to be any term, not just one of the functions in the language, and we can "compose" terms.)

Comment: So they define a “submodel generated by X” in the following way:      Let **A** be a model for L and let X be a nonempty subset of **A**. Let *B* = **intersection symbol** {*C* :  **C** (model) **subset of symbol** **A** and *X* **subset of** *C*} Then there is a submodel **B** subset of **A** with universe *B*. **B** is called the submodel generated by *X*

Comment: @NoahSchweber my reaction was that it should be B (superset symbol) {...  as opposed to B = {...

Comment: @NoahSchweber I get this but why then does it say “B = ...”?

Comment: @mizejonathan17 Why should $B$ be *bigger* than that set? What should be in $B$ that's not in that set? Can you give a particular example of a situation you think it should be bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S=\{t[x_1,\dots,x_n] : t\text{ is a term of $L$ and }x_1,\dots,x_n\in X\}$.  Clearly any submodel $C$ of $A$ that contains $X$ must also contain $S$, since every element of $S$ is obtained by repeatedly applying operations starting from elements of $X$ and $C$ must be closed under the operations.  (More formally, you can prove by induction on terms that each element of $S$ is in $C$.)  So, $S\subseteq B$.

To prove the reverse inclusion, simply observe that $S$ itself is a submodel of $A$: it is closed under all the operations since if you apply an operation to some terms you just get a bigger term using the function symbol corresponding to the operation.  So $S$ is a submodel of $A$ that contains $X$, $B\subseteq S$.